# Retrieving one object from JSON using Angular factory and lodash

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, lodash

I have a locally stored JSON named "Productos", and using UI-router I pass in a $stateParams which I then use to find that object by its unique ID using the new page's controller and a factory shared between several controllers.

Right now my console retrieves the correct id number being passed into the factory function, but once that same number is passed into lodash's _.find the console simple shows an existing [object Object], thus _.find always returns undefined. Oddly, when I try to console.log the productos array inside the _.find, it also simply returns a huge list of [object Object]s. Where am I going so wrong?

```
.controller('DetalleProductoController',
    ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'Productos', 
        function ($scope, $stateParams, Productos) { 

            console.log($stateParams);
            // Recibir el producto por id pasado.
            $scope.producto = Productos.findById($stateParams.id);
            console.log($scope.producto);

}])
```

And the service being used and called...

```
angular.module('MyApp.Services', []);

MyApp.factory('Productos', function (){

    console.log("In Producto Service");

    var productos = [{
        "stockid":"01000001",
        "Nombre":"Articulo 1",
        "Descripcion":"",
        "Precio":140,
        "PrecioAnterior":0,
        "EtiquetaPrecio":"",
        "Puntos":0,
        "Familia":"001",
        "Grupo":"01",
        "Clase":"",
        "Destacado":"N",
        "Etiquetas":"",
        "Rubro":"01",
        "TipoArticulo":""},
    return { 

        todos: function() {
            console.log("Returning Products from local Service");
            return productos;
        },

        destacados: function() {
            return _.filter(productos, function (producto) {
                return producto.Destacado == "S";
            })
        },

        findById: function (ProductoId) {
            console.log("Id passed into factory: " + ProductoId);

                return _.find(productos, function (ProductoId){
                    console.log("id inside the find block is: " + ProductoId);
                    return parseInt(productos.stockid) == parseInt(ProductoId); 
            });
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Ignore the variable productos not closing. It's an array of 70.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable passed into the _.find function is the one of the elements in the collection, not the ID.

So I think it should be something like this:

```
findById: function (ProductoId) {
  return _.find(productos, function (producto) {
    return parseInt(pruducto.stockid) === parseInt(ProductoId);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This actually worked and fixed it. Will mark it an answer when it allows me!